# Boolean difference ("cutter") doubles object instead of cutting

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]

Hello, so I'm building a house which is "cube" on the scene collection. I now want to cut out "Cube 001" from my house which worked for another section of the roof but not here. I did choose "cube" modified boolean, selected "Cube 001" and choose apply but instead of cutting - it doubled the mesh "Cube 001". The problem is make "Cube 001" invisible, the doubled mesh was merged with my house. (Second picture)
Whats the mistake here? How can I prevent the mesh from doubling and instead make it cut out "Cube 001" from "cube"? [image]

[image]

Comment: You have to delete the cutter object after you applied the Boolean modifier. This does not happen automatically.

Comment: You don't have to delete the cutter or apply the Boolean.  Especially if you are using a non-destructive Boolean workflow you don't want to do that. you have to make it invisible,  and the OP has indicated they've done that.

Comment: Your problem seems to be the version of Blender you are using. I tried the same thing with 2.93.5 and there's no problem.  There is a bug in Boolean where exact mode produces errors like this.  Try switching the Boolean to Fast mode and see if that helps.

Comment: @George Tsiklauri if moonboots has answered your question it'd be helpful if you accepted it by clicking the checkmark next to it.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Try fliping the orientation. Sometime the faces are facing the wrong direction.

Answer (score 4):

First thing display your cutter object as a wire so that you can see what's happening:

[image]

In your case the *Fast* option seems to work better for *Difference*. *Exact* seems to bug here, it adds instead of substracting. It may not give the topology you want though, as the roof is not part of the same mesh as the rest of the house:

[image]

When you're good you can apply the modifier, and delete the cutter object if you want.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem in this case, as the OP has indicated that they've hidden the cutter, which gives the same effect.  Which version of Blender are you using?

Comment: I didn't mean that displaying the cutter as a wire was the solution, I advised to do it to make things clearer, from what I understand from the file he shares the main problem seems to be that Exact mode doesn't seem to work as good as Fast

Comment: That's why I wondered which version of Blender you're using.  2.93.5 doesn't seem to exhibit the bug on his file, but obviously 2.93.4 does.

Comment: I've used Blender 3 and it bugs as well, that's why I recommend Fast rather than Exact, Fast works

Comment: weird.  a regression in alpha, I guess.